# Order and limit clauses unexpectedly passed down to scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

(the queries here have no sensible semantic but I chose them for the sake of simplicity)

```ruby
Project.limit(10).where(id: Project.select(:id))
```

generates as expected the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT
  "projects".* 
FROM
  "projects" 
WHERE
  "projects"."id" IN (
    SELECT
     "projects"."id" 
    FROM
      "projects"
) LIMIT 10
```

But if I defined in my `Project` class the method

```ruby
def self.my_filter
  where(id: Project.select(:id))
end
```

Then

```ruby
Project.limit(10).my_filter
```

generates the following query

```sql
SELECT
  "projects".* 
FROM
  "projects" 
WHERE
  "projects"."id" IN (
    SELECT
     "projects"."id" 
    FROM
      "projects" LIMIT 10
) LIMIT 10
```

See how the `LIMIT 10` has now been also applied to the subquery.

Same issue when using a `.order` clause.

It happens with Rails 4.2.2 and Rails 3.2.20. It happens when the subquery is done on the Project table, it does happens if the subquery is done on another table.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here or do you think it is a Rails bug?

A workaround is to build `my_filter` by explicitly adding  `limit(nil).reorder(nil)` to it but it is hackish.

EDIT: another workaround is to append the `limit` clause after the `my_filter` scope: `Project.my_filter.limit(10)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a feature. Class methods work similar to scopes in ActiveRecord models.

And if you want to remove the already added scopes, you can either use `unscoped`, either call the method on a class directly, not on a scope:

```
def self.my_filter
  unscoped.where(id: Project.select(:id))
end

# or

Project.my_filter
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to remove the already added scopes, I just want them to not being applied to the subquery. I need to call the class method on an already built ActiveRecord::Relation instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your class method is applied [in a way you may not be expecting](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L69):

```
Project.limit(10) # => a relation, not the Project class
       .my_filter # => calling a class method on a relation
                  # Does, the following, suddenly:
                  #   scoping { Project.my_filter }
                  # It's a relation's wrapper
```

> - From: .../ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb @ line 281:
> - Owner: `ActiveRecord::Relation`
> - Visibility: public
> - Signature: scoping()
>
> Scope all queries to the current scope.
>
> ```
> Comment.where(post_id: 1).scoping do
>   Comment.first
> end
> # => SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"
> #    WHERE "comments"."post_id" = 1 ORDER BY "comments"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
> ```
>
> Please check `unscoped` if you want to remove all previous scopes (including
>   the `default_scope`) during the execution of a block.

Inside that `scoping` block, your class will include all the scoping rules of a relation it was built from into all queries, as `scoping` will enforce context. This is done so class methods can be properly chained, while still retaining the correct `self`. Of course, when you try using a class method inside the class method, stuff blows up.

In your first, "expected outcome" example, `where` is "natively" defined on relations, so no scope enforcement takes place: it's just not necessary.

Yeah, documentation hints that you can use `unscoped` in your nested query, like so:

```
def my_filter
  where(id: Project.unscoped.select(:id))
end
```

...since that's where you need the "bare basis". Or, as you've already found out, you can just place `limit` at the end:

```
Project.my_filter.limit(10)
```

...here, at the time `my_filter` gets to execute, `scoping` will do effectively nothing: there will be no context built up to this point.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed explanation! In my real codebase I can't apply `limit(10` after `my_filter` (too long too explain why), and `my_filter` is actually something like `def class.my_filter(user); where(id: user.active_projects.select(:id)); end`. If I do `user.active_projects.unscoped.select(:id)` I just lost the filtering on user, ie I get only it generates the plain query "SELECT projects.id from projects". For the moment I just do `user.active_projects.limit(nil).reorder(nil).select(:id)` but is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: @Florent2 `where(id: query_for_ids)` already looks suspicious and solvable with `joins` or `merge`. Could you give a more complete example?

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have something like `where(id: user.administrated_projects.pluck(:id) + user.managed_projects.pluck(:id)` where `User#administrated_projects` and `User#managed_projects` are two `has_many` relationships (using the `through` option to go through permission tables).

Comment: Woohoo! A naïve approach is to unite these two with a `UNION`, and even that requires Arel... Maybe you could make that a scope on `Project`? Like `administered_by(user)` and the likes. That would allow you to use `unscoped` and overall benefit from composability like `administered_by(user).managed_by(user2)`.

Comment: But wouldn't `administered_by(user).managed_by(user)` do a AND? I need a OR.

Comment: No-no-no, that was just an example of what you could gain by doing that. `OR`ing scopes is slightly different. And though possible, I was thinking of doing a different thing here.